# Enable dark mode with each button sharing the same class

Tags: javascript, html, css

**A working example is here (source: css-tricks):** https://codepen.io/carlo-designer/pen/QWveobK

The first button `<button class="btn-toggle">Toggle Dark-Mode</button>` work as intended and activate the dark mode, but not the other too.

Is there a way to trigger the dark mode for each element that has the class `"btn-toggle"` ?

Comment: You need to loop over **btn** because you have more than one Elements. It take only the first one on your code.

Answer (score 1):

Because the function `querySelector()` just get the first element that having such selector. If you want to access all elements with a selector, you should use `querySelectorAll()`.

For example:

1. with `querySelector`

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-toggle");

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var body = document.querySelector('body');
  var isDark = body.classList.contains('dark-theme');
  
  if(isDark)
    body.classList.remove('dark-theme');
  else
    body.classList.add('dark-theme');
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}
body.dark-theme {
  background-color: #121212;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-toggle">Toggle Dark-Mode</button>
<button class="btn-toggle">Toggle Dark-Mode Two</button>
<button class="btn-toggle">Toggle Dark-Mode Three</button>
```

2. with `querySelectorAll`

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-toggle");

btns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var body = document.querySelector('body');
    var isDark = body.classList.contains('dark-theme');

    if(isDark)
      body.classList.remove('dark-theme');
    else
      body.classList.add('dark-theme');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}
body.dark-theme {
  background-color: #121212;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-toggle">Toggle Dark-Mode</button>
<button class="btn-toggle">Toggle Dark-Mode Two</button>
<button class="btn-toggle">Toggle Dark-Mode Three</button>
```